# How to mirror this triangle made using nested for loops

Tags: php

How do I mirror this triangle made with nested for loops ?

```
for($x=0; $x<10; $x++) { //down
  echo '<br>';
  for($y=0; $y<$x; $y++) {
    echo '*';
  }
}
```

I have managed to do this but I can't understand it

```
for($x=1;$x<8;$x++){
    for($y=8;$y>=$x;$y--){
        echo"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    for($z=1;$z<=$x;$z++){
        echo"* ";
    }
echo"<br>";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, which axis are you trying to mirror this?

Comment: Yes I have tried inserting another nested loop with &nbsp but ended up with an infinite loop problem

Comment: We always encourage people to show what they tried, even if it fails, that shows us that you are invested in this. Also, it helps if you can show a sample of the output so that we don't need to do that on our own.

Comment: I updated with a possible solution but I can't understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to rewrite your first one to use some variables that will hopefully make more sense for the changes that we'll introduce. They're aren't wrong, this just helps (at least me) think about it. Also, instead of an HTML `<br />` I'm using a newline, instead of a space I'm using a plus sign, and instead of an asterisk, I'm using a pound sign, just to make it obvious what is going on.

### First example

```php
const LINES = 10;

for ($rows = 0; $rows <= LINES; $rows++) {
    for ($stars = 0; $stars <= $rows; $stars++) {
        echo '#';
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### Result

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########
#########
##########
###########
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/YpYvS

### Second example - extra whitespace to the right

This example is the same as above, however I'm adding some extra white space at the end of the star. The result looks the same as the previous, however if you select the text you'll see those spaces.

```php
const LINES = 10;

for ($rows = 0; $rows <= LINES; $rows++) {
    for ($stars = 0; $stars <= $rows; $stars++) {
        echo '#';
    }
    for ($spaces = LINES; $spaces >= $rows; $spaces--) {
        echo "+";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### Result

```
#+++++++++++
##++++++++++
###+++++++++
####++++++++
#####+++++++
######++++++
#######+++++
########++++
#########+++
##########++
###########+
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/DG34B

### Third example - mirroring

To mirror this, we just need to move the whitespace (pluses in my example), *before* the stars, so just swapping the order of the inner loop:

```php
const LINES = 10;

for ($rows = 0; $rows <= LINES; $rows++) {
    for ($spaces = LINES; $spaces >= $rows; $spaces--) {
        echo "+";
    }
    for ($stars = 0; $stars <= $rows; $stars++) {
        echo '#';
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### Result

```
+++++++++++#
++++++++++##
+++++++++###
++++++++####
+++++++#####
++++++######
+++++#######
++++########
+++#########
++##########
+###########
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/H25Bf

### Fourth example - both sides

If you want to show both sides of the pyramid, you can just keep duplicating things

```php
const LINES = 10;

for ($rows = 0; $rows <= LINES; $rows++) {
    for ($spaces = LINES; $spaces >= $rows; $spaces--) {
        echo "+";
    }
    for ($stars = 0; $stars <= $rows; $stars++) {
        echo '#';
    }
    for ($stars = 0; $stars <= $rows; $stars++) {
        echo '#';
    }
    for ($spaces = LINES; $spaces >= $rows; $spaces--) {
        echo "+";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### Result

```
+++++++++++##+++++++++++
++++++++++####++++++++++
+++++++++######+++++++++
++++++++########++++++++
+++++++##########+++++++
++++++############++++++
+++++##############+++++
++++################++++
+++##################+++
++####################++
+######################+
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/E1oqK

Comment: Thanks ! Yup it worked and I have understood it :)

Comment: And thank you for posting what you tried, a little effort sometimes goes a long way with us on this site.